# Prove Area Triangle ADF = Area Triangle BEF

Tags: triangles

[image]

Given the parallelogram *ABCD*,  $\frac{AD}{AE}$ = $\frac{BF}{FA}$ and $\frac{area of \triangle ADF}{areaof \triangle AEF}$ = $\frac{AD}{AE}$ (or in other words $\frac{area of \triangle ADF}{areaof \triangle AEF}$ = $\frac{BF}{FA}$), prove that *area of* $\triangle$*ADF* = *area of* $\triangle$*BEF*.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Sure. All I could figure out was that the base of $\triangle$BEF and the base of $\triangle$ADF are the proportion $\frac{BF}{FA}$. I also know that the heights of the two triangles in question are in proportion to $\frac{AD}{AE}$, as they are the same heights found in the above proportion. After that, I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the obvious theorem:

> If two triangles have a vertex in common and the sides opposite to
>   that vertex lie on the same line, then the ratio of their areas is
>   equal to the ratio of the opposite sides.

Hence:
$$
{area\triangle BEF\over area\triangle AEF}={BF\over FA}={AD\over AE}=
{area\triangle ADF\over area\triangle AEF}
$$

EDIT.

Notice that $AD/AE=/$ is the same as $BC/AE=/$, and this follows from the similarity of triangles $AEF$ and $CBF$.

Answer (score 0):

Let EI the height of the triangle AEF. Also DH the height of the triangle DAF. We know that the ratio between the height of similar triangle is equal to the ratio between the sides. So $\frac{DH}{EI} = \frac{BF}{FA} $. Now we can write $ DH \cdot FA = BF \cdot EI$. $BF \cdot EI$  is the double of the area of the traingle $ EFB$; $DH \cdot FA$ is the double of the area of $ DAF$. So $ DAF = EFB$ (Area).

Do I have to post an image to clarify?

Comment: Firstly, in your proportion, shouldn't _BF_ and _FA_ be flipped?

Comment: Secondly, how did you get that _BF_* _FB_ is double the area of the triangle? Isn't that just multiplying the base times itself?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's EI

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand how you got your initial proportion. Shouldn't the heights of respective triangles be lined up with the heights of respective sides?

Comment: DAF and FEA are similar

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: And even if this is so, how does that show $\frac{DH}{EI}$ = $\frac{BF}{FA}$ ?

Comment: Let FK the height of the triangle ADF and EAF. This two triangle have the same coincident height so they are similar. The ratio is $\frac{AD}{AE}$...

Comment: Is _FK_ the height of ADF or AEF? I don't know that they have the same height!

Comment: It' s in common because FK is perpendicular to DE

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you post a picture?

Comment: I can't post an image because it's to big, but it can be understood... See the picture of the author...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all explained in the figure below.
[image]

Comment: What is k in your equations? And I don't understand what you mean when you wrote "AE = k.AD; AF = k.BF"?

Comment: k is the ratio AE/AD. k = AE/AD = AF/BF